# Recuperar nodo xml con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Tengo un fichero xml con una serie de datos entre los que hay una ID por nodo.
El fichero xml es de este tipo:

```
<events>
  <event id="001" title="title1" imageurl="evento1.jpg">
     <category>fotografia</category>
     <ciudad>MADRID</ciudad>
     <date>02 NOVIEMBRE</date>
     <hour>12:30 AM</hour>
     <url>evento.html</url>
  </event>
  <event id="002" title="title2" imageurl="evento2.jpg">
     <category>producto</category>
     <ciudad>MADRID</ciudad>
     <date>05 NOVIEMBRE</date>
     <hour>18:00 PM</hour>
     <url>evento.html</url>
  </event>
  <event id="003" title="title3" imageurl="evento3.jpg">
     <category>fotografia</category>
     <ciudad>MADRID</ciudad>
     <date>07 NOVIEMBRE</date>
     <hour>12:30 PM</hour>
     <url>evento.html</url>
  </event>
  <event id="004" title="title4" imageurl="evento4.jpg">
     <category>producto</category>
     <ciudad>VALENCIA</ciudad>
     <date>28 NOVIEMBRE</date>
     <hour>18:00 PM</hour>
     <url>evento.html</url>
  </event>
```

Recibo una ID (X) por url que recojo en una variable.
Ahora la duda es: ¿Como puedo recuperar los datos del nodo con ID (X)?
No he trabajado nunca recuperando datos de XML y estoy un poco perdido.

Gracias de antemano.

Actualizo con el código para recuperar el xml:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $.get('data-home.xml', function(d){

    $(d).find('event').each(function(){

        var $event = $(this);
        var title = $event.attr("title");
        var id = $event.find('id').text();
        var category = $event.find('category').text();
        var ciudad = $event.find('ciudad').text();
        var date = $event.find('date').text();
        var hour = $event.find('hour').text();
        var url = $event.find('url').text();
        var btntxt = $event.find('btntxt').text();
        var imageurl = $event.attr('imageurl');

        //var html = '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> <img class="bookImage" alt="" src="' + imageurl + '" />';
        var html = '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 evento-'+ category +'"><div id="evento-box" class="'+ category +'" style="background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 45%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%), url(images/' + imageurl + '");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size: cover;">';
        html += '<p class="fecha">' + date + ' | ' + hour + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="ciudad">' + ciudad + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="title">' + title + '</p>';
        //html += '<p> ' + category + '</p>' ;
        html += '<a class="btn btn-default btn-goto" href="' + url + '?id=' + id + '">'+ btntxt +'</a>' ;
        html += '</div></div>';

        $('#eventos').append($(html));
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Faltan datos en tu pregunta. ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Tienes algún error en concreto? ¿De dónde viene el XML y cómo lo recuperas?, etc.

Comment: El xml es un fichero que recojo con $.get('data.xml', function(d){}. Está en el mismo servidor que el resto de  scripts.

Comment: El xml es un fichero que recojo con $.get('data.xml', function(d){}. Está en el mismo servidor que el resto de  scripts.
Creo que puedo esplicar la idea mejor.
Tengo un xml del que saco datos de eventos y los pinto en un HTML. Con los datos genero una url con la ID de cada evento y con destino otro HTML donde quiero mostrar los datos del evento con la ID que mando por url.
Similar a mostrar un listado de post y al hacer click en el LEER MAS, te manda al post con la ID seleccionada.He conseguido leer el XML pero no se leer solamente la parte del XML que tiene la ID que recibo por url.

Comment: Ya, pero muestra el código que estás usando para recuperar el XML y para leerlo, así podremos ayudarte a completarlo ¿no? Al no poder el código no podemos aventurarnos a una respuesta en el aire.

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendido mal la pregunta, estás recuperando un XML y estás añadiendo todos los elementos del XML al HTML, pero tú solo quieres que se añada un solo elemento, el elemento que recuperas por parametro. Si éste es el caso tu función quedará algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    var idActual = 'XML_ID_ACTUAL'; //Este es el id que recuperas

    $.get('data-home.xml', function(d){

    $(d).find('event').each(function(){

       var id = $event.find('id').text();

       if(idActual == id){ //Lo comparas con el id del XML para añadirlo al HTML

        var $event = $(this);
        var title = $event.attr("title");
        var category = $event.find('category').text();
        var ciudad = $event.find('ciudad').text();
        var date = $event.find('date').text();
        var hour = $event.find('hour').text();
        var url = $event.find('url').text();
        var btntxt = $event.find('btntxt').text();
        var imageurl = $event.attr('imageurl');

        //var html = '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> <img class="bookImage" alt="" src="' + imageurl + '" />';
        var html = '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 evento-'+ category +'"><div id="evento-box" class="'+ category +'" style="background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 45%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%), url(images/' + imageurl + '");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size: cover;">';
        html += '<p class="fecha">' + date + ' | ' + hour + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="ciudad">' + ciudad + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="title">' + title + '</p>';
        //html += '<p> ' + category + '</p>' ;
        html += '<a class="btn btn-default btn-goto" href="' + url + '?id=' + id + '">'+ btntxt +'</a>' ;
        html += '</div></div>';

        $('#eventos').append($(html));

      }

    });
});
```